# Performance issue in iText7 compared to iTextsharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I have tested in iTextsharp and iText7 for HTML to PDF conversion. Based on the performance iTextsharp is taking 3 minutes for 10000 PDF creation. But iText7 taking 17 minutes for 10000 PDF creation.

Example of iText7 PDF conversion :

```
  Dim m As New MemoryStream
    HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(HTML, m)
    Dim bytes As Byte()
    bytes = m.ToArray()
    File.WriteAllBytes("E:\testpdf.pdf", bytes)
```

How to improve performance of HTML to PDF conversion in iText7?

Comment: Please provide your entire test case, including HTML.

Comment: Someone else asked a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559611/itext7-performance-issue-compared-with-itextsharp, but with a bit more information (still not enough to be able to answer the question).